# Is it possible to field map wpforms data to woocommerce products and add the items to cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wpforms elite (with webhooks) in hopes to simplify the order process for woocommerce customers.

When a user submits the form at this url, http://implantlogic.wpengine.com/device-selection/ I hope to have products added to the cart based on users selections.

For example, if the user selects tooth one on the tooth selection page of the form, this product will need to be added to the cart with all fields populated http://implantlogic.wpengine.com/product/tooth-1/ and this applies to other things the user selects on the form as well which would trigger simple field mapping or the addition of simple products to the cart.

Right now I just need to know if this is possible or if I should seek other methods to solve this issue and create the same experience.

Comment: I can only get you have way there. I have used [this before](https://gist.github.com/lukecav/ab9dbdee88de686ce6b59c264cde8970) to add products to the cart from a URL. You could send people to such a URL after they fill out the form, but I don't know how to add products with specific product fields already selected.

Comment: WP Forms does have PayPal/Stripe/Authorize.net addons. You could just skip the WooCommerce checkout and process the payment with WP Forms.

Comment: The reason that I need to link it to woocommerce is so that multiple forms can be filled out, and so that we can take full advantage of the returns, shipping, and checkout features of woocommerce. If i use their payment method it only allows users to fill out the form once then pay.